# How to create Linux header for newly compiled kernel?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-modules

In Debian when I want to compile my kernel module I need to install `linux-header-*` package and then I need to write some `makefile` like this:

```
obj-m := hello.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

But now I have downloaded specific kenel from kernel.org and compile it. So how can I address the `KDIR` variable in my `makefile`?

I want to know, how Debian mainteners create `linux-header-*` packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to.

```
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

Presumes you are building a module for the currently running kernel, since it uses `$(shell uname -r)` to complete the path.  When you build a kernel and run `make modules_install`, the modules are copied into a corresponding directory in `/lib/modules` -- this will match the output of `uname -r` for that kernel.

The `build` subdirectory is a link to the kernel source tree.  So don't erase that, obviously.

If you are compiling for a different kernel than the running one, just set `KDIR` to the source directory where you built it.

Comment: Great, yes I created linux headers. but now, how can I create `build` subdirectory? In my debian, build doesn't link to all kernel source tree.

Comment: `build` doesn't even have to be there at all for the system to work, in fact.  But it does if you want to use that makefile with the running kernel.  If there's a build directory in the distro `/lib/modules/X.x-whatever`, whatever it is is at least *part* of a source tree -- that probably gets installed when you install a "kernel sources" package.  If it's empty or not there, that's because you haven't installed such a package.  But you don't need it if you are building from a source you downloaded yourself.  The distro stuff won't be involved anyway.