# How to create /usr/src/linux-headers-{version} files

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, header-file

I am trying to compile a custom kernel for Nvidia's Jetson TK1 board, and it seems that as well as the kernel itself (zImage) I will need `/usr/src/linux-headers-{version}` and `/lib/modules/{version}`.

However I can't see how to create the linux-headers.  I have tried running `make headers_install` but it does not seem to create the same type of output as what I see in other `/usr/src/linux-headers` directories.

I've seen other similar questions such as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104131/how-to-create-linux-header-for-newly-compiled-kernel), however this assumes you are building the same version as you are running, where I am trying to build with a different LOCAL_VERSION.

I am starting from a "Linux4Tegra" distro, however, I am attempting to make a custom system based on Ubuntu Core.

**To clarify**, I am trying to create a kernel with my own LOCAL_VERSION, i.e., my own version, not an existing version in any repository.  I would like to generate the headers that match this.  So installing a linux-headers-xxx package will not address my problem.

My question is how are these packages initially created from the linux source?

When I look at the files in the existing headers directories, it contains references to that kernel version, so I am assuming that this has been generated from that version of the linux source.  How can I generate these?  When someone is compiling a version of the kernel, surely they generate these files somehow?

Comment: add your distro to the post please

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: How does the output vary from what you'd normally see in /usr/src/linux-headers?

Comment: Not at my computer until tomorrow, but the output is basically completely different. No commonality whatsoever as far as I could see.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer. I recently encountered this problem and I found a possible answer.

Suppose you want to install the kernel header file to `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.3`. The compiled kernel source tree is located `/path/to/compiled/linux-4.15.3/`

first, unpack a clean kernel source tree

```
tar xvf linux-4.15.3.tar.xz
cd linux-4.15.3/
```

second, copy you `.config` file to the directory

```
cp /path/to/compiled/linux-4.15.3/.config .
```

third, run it and then delete .config file in source directory to get a clean kernel source

```
make O=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.3 oldconfig
rm .config
```

fourth, run the `modules_prepare` make target

```
make O=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.3 modules_prepare
```

Finally, delete useless things, and copy the necessary things

```
rm /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.3/source
cp /path/to/compiled/linux-4.15.3/Module.symvers /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.3
```

Now, the `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.3` directory is able to build the module.

Documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt tell us `modules_prepare`

> This will make sure the kernel contains the information required. The target exists solely as a simple way to prepare a kernel source tree for building external modules.
>
> NOTE: "modules_prepare" will not build Module.symvers even if CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is set; therefore, a full kernel build needs to be executed to make module versioning work.

Comment: This does not work for a strange reason:

~$ tar -xf linux-5.10.10.tar.xz
~$ cd linux-5.10.10/
~/linux-5.10.10$ make mrproper
~/linux-5.10.10$ cp ~/config_sys .config
~/linux-5.10.10$ make O=/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.10 oldconfig
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.10'
***
*** The source tree is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
*** in /home/nuclear/linux-5.10.10
***
make[1]: *** [/home/nuclear/linux-5.10.10/Makefile:547: outputmakefile] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.10'
make: *** [Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2